# LibSVM: -wi option (weight selection) during cross-validation and testing

Tags: classification, libsvm

I need help about the weight option of libSVM. I'm confused at some point; should we also use the -wi option while doing cross-validation? If so, should we use the calculated weights of the whole data or the calculated weights according to the v-1 subsets (for v-fold cross-validation)? And my second question is should we use -wi option during predict? If so, should we use the calculated weights during training or should we calculate the weights according to the distribution of negative and positive instances in the test data?

For example; we have 50 + data and 200 - data. So after calculating the best c and gamma parameter values we will use -w1 4 -w-1 1 options while training. But what about training during grid search and cross validation? Let's say we are performing 5-fold cross-validation. While training on each remaining 4 subsets, the distribution of negative and possitive instances will probably change. So should we recalculate the weights during this 5-fold cross validation?

Besides shoud we use -w1 4 -w-1 1 options while testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

To answer your first question, if you are applying non-trivial weights to a subset of classes during model training, then you should do the same throughout your training/tuning which includes cross-validation based tuning of C and gamma (otherwise you would be tuning the model based on the cost-sensitive objective/risk/loss function which is different from the one you are actualy specifying by enabling non-trivial class weights)

The class weights are external to libSVM in the sense that they are not calculated by libSVM - that command-line option allows a user to set his/her own class weights to emphasize/reduce importance of a subset of classes. Some people tune the class weights as well but that is a different story.

As for the prediction, the class weights are not used there explicitly (since they come in as a "tweak" to the objective/risk/loss function during the model training/tuning stage so the resulting model is already "aware" of the weights)